# Jquery code not working on site but does in fiddle

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of inputs that has several parents div and then multiple children checkboxes under each parent. there is only 1 level of children.(see links below)

Under each parent I have check boxes (MUST USE checkboxes, rather than radio buttons) and should only allow a single selection of the children within each parent.

I am using the following code on within a fiddle - and it works OK, but applying this to the application is failing, yet there are no error chrome shows to debug what is going on...

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function () {
    var checkedState = $(this).attr("checked");
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().find('input[type=checkbox]:checked').removeAttr("checked");
    $(this).attr("checked", checkedState);
});
```

A working example of what I am trying to achieve can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/EYtx8/

The dev site that's not working can be found here: http://protoys.gentex.com.au/Products/Catalogue (The page load is slow, I know), you will note that all check boxes can be selected, which is what I am trying to avoid.

As a side note people have mentioned that its not within the DOM. but a wrapped in a

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

Here is the full script on the dev site

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

//Update the is in stock flag, by altering the criteria input fields.
$("input[[id*='chkInStock']]").change(function() {
    if ($("input[[id*='chkInStock']]").prop('checked') == true) $("input[[id*='nbs-min']]").val('1');
    if ($("input[[id*='chkInStock']]").prop('checked') == false) $("input[[id*='nbs-min']]").val('0');
});

if ('[Settings:chktextsearch]'=='False')
{
    // ALL Text search is turned off in the settings, so use JS to update the "disabledsearchtokens" for all text search tokens -->
    var disabledlist = $("input[[id*='disabledsearchtokens']]").val();
    if (disabledlist.indexOf('search0;') == -1) disabledlist = disabledlist + 'search0;';
    if (disabledlist.indexOf('search1;') == -1) disabledlist = disabledlist + 'search1;';
    if (disabledlist.indexOf('search2;') == -1) disabledlist = disabledlist + 'search2;';
    if (disabledlist.indexOf('search3;') == -1) disabledlist = disabledlist + 'search3;';
    if (disabledlist.indexOf('search4;') == -1) disabledlist = disabledlist + 'search4;';
    if (disabledlist.indexOf('search5;') == -1) disabledlist = disabledlist + 'search5;';
    if (disabledlist.indexOf('search6;') == -1) disabledlist = disabledlist + 'search6;';
    if (disabledlist.indexOf('search7;') == -1) disabledlist = disabledlist + 'search7;';
    if (disabledlist.indexOf('search8;') == -1) disabledlist = disabledlist + 'search8;';
    // Update disabled fields to the postback field -->
    $("input[[id*='disabledsearchtokens']]").val(disabledlist);
   }

   $('input[type=checkbox]').click(function () {
      var checkedState = $(this).attr("checked");           

     $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().find('input[type=checkbox]:checked').removeAttr("checked");
   $(this).attr("checked", checkedState);
    });

    $('label').each(function () {
       var $this = $(this);
      $this.html($this.text().replace(/^(\.+)/g, '<span style="display:none">$1</span><span     class="Child">'));
         });
     });

    </script>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I see you MUST use checkbox, but I think is going to be rather confusing to your users: when someone see checkboxes usually is for selecting more than one. As you point out, the best html tag for this is radio button (and you wouldn't have this headaches...). Last question, just curiosity, why you must use it?

Comment: Customer strange request - they want to trial this first and then if they don't like it change back to all selections... You gotta give them what they want even after advising...

Comment: no errors in console?

Answer (score 3):

There could be 2 problems...

1. The code is not inside dom ready handler
2. Using attr() instead of .prop() to set the checked property.

So try

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('input[type=checkbox]').click(function () {
        //if the markup in the jsfiddle is same as the one in your page then try
        $(this).closest('table').find('input[type=checkbox]:checked').not(this).prop("checked", false);
    });
})
```

Note: Instead of using chained .parent() calls use .closest()

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4ExEf/)

Comment: I like this, much more elegant - I have made the change, but yet the code does not apply on the dev site. Yes its in the dom handler (See edits above)

Answer (score 0):

Probably because you're not wrapping your code inside DOM ready handler which `jsFiddle` already did it for you, try to do:

```
$(function() {
    $('input[type=checkbox]').click(function () {
        var checkedState = $(this).attr("checked");
        $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().find('input[type=checkbox]:checked').removeAttr("checked");
        $(this).attr("checked", checkedState);
    });
});
```

Comment: Sure am - I have shown this in a new edit of the original post

Answer (score 0):

After reading your comment I though this could works:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type=checkbox]').click(function () {
        $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().find('input[type=checkbox]:checked').removeAttr("checked");            
        $(this).attr("checked", "checked");            
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Only reason I can think of is your JS code execution is taking place before the DOM build up. Place your code inside `$(document ).ready(handler)` . Checkout jquery documentation for more details http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 0):

try with this:

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    $('input[type=checkbox]').click(function () {
        var checkedState = $(this).attr("checked");
        $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().find('input[type=checkbox]:checked').removeAttr("checked");
        $(this).attr("checked", checkedState);
    });
});
```

Comment: Its wrapped in $(document).ready( function(){ with several functions above it

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is that some selectors are not selecting the targeted element or if you have the correct selector (because i do not know what is actually happening on the codes ) try  this simple code that I had wrote for you. Get the logic and implement to what you need (if I did get your what you want to accomplish).

```
<input type="checkbox" class="check" name="trythis">try
<input type="checkbox" class="check" name="trythis">try
<input type="checkbox" class="check" name="trythis">try
<input type="checkbox" class="check" name="trythis">try

$('input[type=checkbox]').on('click', function() { 
   var thisis = $(this);
   $('.check').each(function() { 
      $(this).prop('checked', false);
   });

    $(thisis).prop('checked', true);

});
```

Check out the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nesmar/rQC7r/1/) here

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I would try with "on" instead of a direct "click", to be sure that you're attaching the handler to the dom element. Try to change:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function () {
    var checkedState = $(this).attr("checked");           

$(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().find('input[type=checkbox]:checked').removeAttr("checked");
$(this).attr("checked", checkedState);
});
```

for:

```
$(document).on('click', 'input[type=checkbox]', function(){
   var checkedState = $(this).attr("checked");

   $(this).closest('table').find('input[type=checkbox]:checked').removeAttr("checked");
   $(this).attr("checked", checkedState); 
});
```

This is a typical thing that happens when you are loading the markup via AJAX, I don't know if it's your case. I've also added the closest as @Arun P Johny suggests